# Waiting for all promises called in a loop to finish

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I'm using [the axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) promise library, but my question applies more generally I think.  Right now I'm looping over some data and making a single REST call per iteration.
As each call completes I need to add the return value to an object.  At a high level, it looks like this:

```
var mainObject = {};

myArrayOfData.forEach(function(singleElement){
  myUrl = singleElement.webAddress;
  axios.get(myUrl)
  .then(function(response) {
    mainObject[response.identifier] = response.value;
   });
});

console.log(convertToStringValue(mainObject));
```

What's happening of course is when I call `console.log` the `mainObject` doesn't have any data in it yet, since axios is still reaching out.  What's a good way of dealing with this situation?

Axios does have an `all` method along with a sister `spread` one, but they appear to be of use if you know ahead of time how many calls you'll be making, whereas in my case I don't know how many loop iterations there will be.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need to collect all of your promises in an array and then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```js
// Example of gathering latest Stack Exchange questions across multiple sites
// Helpers for example
const apiUrl = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?pagesize=1&order=desc&sort=activity&site=',
    sites = ['stackoverflow', 'ubuntu', 'superuser'],
    myArrayOfData = sites.map(function (site) {
        return {webAddress: apiUrl + site};
    });

function convertToStringValue(obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj, null, '\t');
}

// Original question code
let mainObject = {},
    promises = [];

myArrayOfData.forEach(function (singleElement) {
    const myUrl = singleElement.webAddress;
    promises.push(axios.get(myUrl));
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) {
    results.forEach(function (response) {
        const question = response.data.items[0];
        mainObject[question.question_id] = {
            title: question.title,
            link: question.link
        };
    });

    console.log(convertToStringValue(mainObject));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.19.2/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

It's described in [axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/d35b5b5902f72305216f245cc58bc2231470fb19/README.md#example) (Performing multiple concurrent requests section).

Before May 2020 it was possible to do with axios.all(), [which is now deprecated](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/d35b5b5902f72305216f245cc58bc2231470fb19/README.md#concurrency-deprecated).