# Cannot assign axios response value to a variable - vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex

I created an array `lists` that contains a few strings.
Now I want to loop through `lists` (i.e., in `getSubs()`) and make an Axios request. This request should contain one string from `lists` each time.

*My code:*

```
computed: {
  subscribers: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.state.subscribers;
    },
    set(value) {
      this.$store.commit('updateSubscribers', value);
    },
  },
},
methods: {
  getLodzkie() {
    axios
      .get(`correct_domain/lodzkietargi/get`)
      .then((response) => {
        this.subscribers = [];
        this.subscribers.push.apply(this.subscribers, response.data)
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
  },
  getSubs() {
    function getSub(value) {
      axios
      .get(`correct_domain/${value}/get`)
      .then((response) => {
        this.subscribers.push.apply(this.subscribers, response.data)
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
      console.log(value);
    }
    this.lists.forEach(function(entry) {
      getSub.call(null, entry);
    });
  },
```

`getLodzkie()` works beautifully

Comment: Consider axios.all. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37213892/3585500

Answer (score 1):

Thank You a lot @ourmandave. That helped me perfectly.

Rewrote function below:

```
getSubs() {
  let listsReqs = this.lists.map(list => {
    return axios.get(`correct_domain/${list}/get`);
  });
  axios.all(listsReqs)
  .then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
    responses.forEach(res => this.subscribers.push.apply(this.subscribers, res.data));
  })
)},
```